# How to find a container image tag/label from its hash

Tags: docker, docker-registry, podman, skopeo

I have a use case I need to find the image tag from its hashed format.

for example, if I have this image

```
quay.io/containerdisks/centos-stream@sha256:0c8d8b253a0b729c602efe45a5bc4640b3d4161b6924db3def2e7a76296e42c9
```

I would like to find one or more labels that point to this image.
At the moment the only option I know of is to "brute-force" it by fetching all the labels related to this image and checking the digest of each against the hash I'm looking for.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag listing only includes tags, not the digests for each of those tags (though I'd like to see that improved). So you're left with brute forcing a digest check against each tag. With [regctl](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) that looks like:

```bash
for tag in $(regctl tag ls quay.io/containerdisks/centos-stream); do
  echo "${tag}: $(regctl image digest quay.io/containerdisks/centos-stream:${tag})"
done | grep "sha256:0c8"
```

Which lists the following matches:

```
9: sha256:0c8d8b253a0b729c602efe45a5bc4640b3d4161b6924db3def2e7a76296e42c9
9-20220829.0: sha256:0c8d8b253a0b729c602efe45a5bc4640b3d4161b6924db3def2e7a76296e42c9
9-2209010207: sha256:0c8d8b253a0b729c602efe45a5bc4640b3d4161b6924db3def2e7a76296e42c9
```

Note that the image digest command here only runs a HEAD request to the registry, so it doesn't download the image and should be relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks, but it's exactly what I was trying to avoid, as some of the repos I work with have a lot of tags.

Comment: If you are making the image reference, then include the tag in there. `registry.example.org/repo:tag@sha256:...`. The value of `tag` is ignored, but can be useful as documentation to yourself to know what tag that digest belonged to at one point.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know, I was not familiar with `regctl` tool

Comment: @Rabin regctl is written by myself. The other good project in this space is crane from go-containerregistry. Skopeo also plays in this space, but they don't have a minimal manifest HEAD command.

Answer (score 1):

Another iteration on @BMitch answer is to use the `parallel` to make several queries in parallel, which reduces the time to query all the tags.

```bash
skopeo list-tags docker://quay.io/containerdisks/centos-stream \
 | jq -r '.Tags[]' \
 | parallel bash -c "\"printf \"%-16s\" {} '-> ' && skopeo inspect -n docker://quay.io/containerdisks/centos-stream:{} --format '{{ .Digest }}'\"" \
 | grep 'sha256:0c8'
```

Comment: Note that skopeo is querying the /v2 endpoint, running a manifest get, pulling the config blob, and running a tag listing, for each inspect. While `crane digest` and `regctl image digest` each do a single manifest head request. So if you need to run a lot of these, the latter two would be much more efficient.